# Make owl-carousel images responsive

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I am trying to get my owl-carousel to be responsive (in Bootstrap-3). I tried it with width:100% and height:auto, but no success. Is it possible to make them responsive?

I only post here relevant code.

```css
.container-carousel {
 width:100%
}


#main-slider .carousel .slider-img {
    text-align:right;
    position:absolute
}

#main-slider .carousel .item {
    background-position:50%;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-size:cover;
    left:0!important;
    opacity:0;
    top:0;
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    display:block!important;
    height:730px;
 margin-bottom:20px;
    -webkit-transition:opacity ease-in-out 500ms;
    -moz-transition:opacity ease-in-out 500ms;
    -o-transition:opacity ease-in-out 500ms;
    transition:opacity ease-in-out 500ms
}

#main-slider .carousel .item:first-child {
    top:auto;
    position:relative
}

#main-slider .carousel .item.active {
    opacity:1;
    -webkit-transition:opacity ease-in-out 500ms;
    -moz-transition:opacity ease-in-out 500ms;
    -o-transition:opacity ease-in-out 500ms;
    transition:opacity ease-in-out 500ms;
    z-index:1
}

#main-slider .prev,#main-slider .next {
    position:absolute;
    top:50%;
    background-color:#c52d2f;
    color:#fff;
    display:inline-block;
    margin-top:-25px;
    height:40px;
    line-height:40px;
    width:40px;
    line-height:40px;
    text-align:center;
    border-radius:0;
    z-index:5
}

#main-slider .active .animation.animated-item-1 {
    -webkit-animation:fadeInUp 300ms linear 300ms both;
    -moz-animation:fadeInUp 300ms linear 300ms both;
    -o-animation:fadeInUp 300ms linear 300ms both;
    -ms-animation:fadeInUp 300ms linear 300ms both;
    animation:fadeInUp 300ms linear 300ms both;
    background:#fff;
    background:rgba(255,255,255,.7)
}

#main-slider .active .animation.animated-item-2 {
    -webkit-animation:fadeInUp 300ms linear 600ms both;
    -moz-animation:fadeInUp 300ms linear 600ms both;
    -o-animation:fadeInUp 300ms linear 600ms both;
    -ms-animation:fadeInUp 300ms linear 600ms both;
    animation:fadeInUp 300ms linear 600ms both
}
```

```html
<div class="container-carousel">
<section id="main-slider" class="root-sec scroll-section no-margin">
        <div class="carousel slide">
            <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                <li data-target="#main-slider" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                <li data-target="#main-slider" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                <li data-target="#main-slider" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    <li data-target="#main-slider" data-slide-to="3"></li>
                <li data-target="#main-slider" data-slide-to="4"></li>
    <li data-target="#main-slider" data-slide-to="5"></li>
            </ol>
            <div class="carousel-inner">

    <div class="item active" style="background-image: url1>
                    <div class="container">
                        

    <div class="item" style="background-image: url2>
                   <div class="container">

    <div class="item" style="background-image: url3>
                    <div class="container">
                     

    <div class="item" style="background-image: url4>
                    <div class="container">
```

Comment: What do you mean by responsive?

Comment: @frosty - that the images scale appropriately per device dimensions, desktop, tablet, mobile, etc.

Comment: You should use JavaScript to get the screen width, then use that to determine the image width.

Comment: @frosty - why Javascript? I use Bootstrap-3

Comment: Because it's effective and it works?

Comment: You can do everything you want to do, and more, with just JavaScript and jQuery.

Comment: @frosty - sure, but I prefer to solve this with html and css, thanks.

Comment: Ha. You can't. It's not going to work with just html and css.

Comment: @frosty - ok then please show me how.

Comment: @frosty - i solved it by changing the height:730px to height:auto. So yes, I can!

Comment: That's makes it so that the parent div is as high as the childs.

Comment: And it's also on by default. Just taking off height: 730px will make the parent div fit the contents of the childs. Is that what you were trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 1):

I solved it simply by changing the height:730px to height:auto.
That was it.

Answer (score -1):

You should use JavaScript to get the screen width, then use that to determine the image width:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js">

<script>

$(function(){

var screenWidth = screen.width; //get the screen width in pixels
var pixelsPerPercentage = screenWidth*.01; //get the pixels per percentage
var imageWidthInPer = 50; //set the variable of the width of the image in percentages
var imageWidthInPix = imageWidthInPer*pixelsPerPercentage; //set the variable of the width of the image in pixels

$(#+"image").width(imageWidth+"px"); //set the width of the image in pixels

});

</script>
```